# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4n+3}{3n-1}\right)=\frac43$ using $\epsilon , \delta$ definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I know how to find limits, yet proving those limits exists using this technique is still tricky for me.

Is the following proof valid?:

[image]

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The one complaint I would have is that the implications are in the wrong direction for the required proof. You've shown them in the direction you followed them in coming up with a suitable $\delta$, but it's the fact that they work in the other direction (for example, **if** $\frac2\epsilon<n-1$ **then** $\frac2{n-1}<\epsilon$) that actually proves the theorem.

Comment: David K could you please post your proof than? I'm not sure I fully understand it

Comment: It is ok but I dont like very much the bound $\frac{2}{|n-1|}$ because is not defined for $n=1$. Observe that $\frac{13}{|9n-3|}<\frac{13}{n+1}$ because $|9n-3|>n+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_{\ge 0}$.